# Get check box value with js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My check box name is in array:-

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subCat[]" value="1" id="subcat">
<input type="checkbox" name="subCat[]" value="2" id="subcat">
<input type="checkbox" name="subCat[]" value="3" id="subcat">
<button>Click</button>
```

I want to get Check box value on click button

Comment: '$("input[type='checkbox']").val();'

Comment: you want value of checked checkbox or every value of  each check box ?

Comment: Any one value of check box for validation purpose .

Comment: i dont understand your mean by any one value

Comment: i want to validate if user check any checkbox than we get true or false. it's only use for validation purpose..

Comment: i write code for you but unable to see add answer button in  your question